# Include php file which alreay includes another using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Suppose i have a file demo.php & it includes info.php . If i load demo.php using Jquery in my index.php will it work? ie. the information in info.php will be included or not?

Comment: try it and see!

Comment: @user2310289  also wanted to know if it is bad practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will work, but be sure that links in the "info.php" are connected properly.

---

e.g :

1- index.php
2- demo.php - includes (info.php).

---

loading(including) demo.php in index.php will make file "index.php" - load all contents of demo.php.